# which is better for live server wamp or xampp?

Tags: xampp, server, wamp, live

Hello i have hosted my website on VPS windows 2008 r2 using wamp server, but i want to know which webserver is better for live server ,wamp or xampp ,because a lot of people visit my website.

Comment: Those (http://www.wampserver.com/en/ and https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html) are intended for development, not production, so none of them are suited for a live server. Unless you're talking about something else, in which case could you please clarify ?

Comment: thank you but IIS 8.0 is for live server?

Answer (score 0):

Wamp and xampp are all using aparche as web service. so there in no difference in term of web server. however wamp and xampp mainly designed for easy development environment set up. for production you may want to set up the environment from ground up. if you going to host with windows, The IIS may be the better fit.